# Python find_element in find_elements problem?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Good day everyone:

I’d like to get the basketball game data from the web include league , date, time and score ….

The first level for loop works fine to get every league title

`for league in leagues:`

But the second level for loop

`for row in _rows:`

I always get all leagues rows ,I just need data for league by league

What should I do to fix it?

Any help will greatly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1500,1350)

# open url (sorry for the url , cause system always report its a spam)
driver.get("https://"+"we"+"b2."+"sa8"+"8"+"88.n"+"et"+"/sp"+"ort/Ga"+"mes.aspxdevice=pc")

# jump to basketball
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menuList"]/div/ul/li[3]/div[2]/a[1]') 
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()
time.sleep(1)

# date menu
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="chooseDate"]')
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()

# jump to date 1
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dateOption"]/a[1]/span[1]')
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()

# close AD by double clicl
locator = (By.ID, 'btn_close') 
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()

# list all leagues schedule
leagues = []
leagues = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scheduleBottom"]/table[*]')
for league in leagues:
    #print("Block.text=",Block.text,"\n")
    #_rows = Block.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    league_Title = league.find_element(By.TAG_NAME ,'caption')
    _rows = []
    _rows = league.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, '_mainRow') or contains(@id, '_secondRow')]")
    print("\nleague : ",league_Title.text, 'len(_rows)=',len(_rows))
    for row in _rows:
        print(league_Title,row.text) #," / _rows=",_rows)
        # first_rows = Block.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, '_mainRow')]")
        # second_rows = Block.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, '_secondRow')]")
        print("\trow : ",row.text)
        time.sleep(1)

time.sleep(120)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: you have to start xpath with `.` (dot) to create relative xpath - and relative xpath will search only in current `league`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run code because page shows `Error 404`.

**EDIT:** in question you forgot `?` in `Games.aspx?device=pc` and this made problem with `404`

---

You have to use dot `.` at the beginning of `xpath` to use path relative to `league`

```
_rows = league.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//...rest...")  # <-- dot before `//`
```

You use absolute `xpath` and it searchs in full HTML.

---

**EDIT:**

Partial result with dot in xpath:

I used `lang=3` to get English text,

And I used `a[2]` to select second date (`03 / 06 (Sun)`) because first date (`03 / 05 (Sat)`)  was empty (no matches)

url: https://web2.sa8888.net/sport/Games.aspx?lang=3&device=pc

```
len(leagues): 115

league: NBA len(_rows)= 12
    row: 06:05 Finished Dallas Mavericks 26 25 34 29 114 | Live Update
    row: Sacramento Kings 36 29 27 21 113
    row: 08:05 Finished Charlotte Hornets 31 31 37 24 123 | Live Update
    row: San Antonio Spurs 30 30 37 20 117
    row: 09:05 Finished Miami Heat 22 32 19 26 99 | Live Update
    row: Philadelphia 76ers 14 26 28 14 82
    row: 09:05 Finished Memphis Grizzlies 31 37 29 27 124 | Live Update
    row: Orlando Magic 29 16 29 22 96
    row: 09:05 Finished Minnesota Timberwolves 32 31 46 26 135 | Live Update
    row: Portland Trail Blazers 34 30 37 20 121
    row: 09:35 Finished Los Angeles Lakers 32 30 27 35 124 | Live Update
    row: Golden State Warriors 25 42 27 22 116
---

league: NBA GATORADE LEAGUE len(_rows)= 8
    row: 08:00 Finished Delaware Blue Coats 42 34 37 33 146 | Live Update
    row: Westchester Knicks 28 28 24 31 111
    row: 09:00 Finished Austin Spurs 35 21 23 31 110 | Live Update
    row: Salt Lake City Stars 30 32 21 17 100
    row: 09:00 Finished Wisconsin Herd 26 30 20 38 114 | Live Update
    row: Capital City Go-Go 27 31 32 38 128
    row: 11:00 Finished Santa Cruz Warriors 36 19 17 27 99 | Live Update
    row: Memphis Hustle 26 29 22 30 107
---

league: CHINA PROFESSIONAL BASKETBALL LEAGUE len(_rows)= 12
    row: 11:00 Finished Fujian Sturgeons 37 21 27 32 117 | Live Update
    row: Ningbo Rockets 24 28 34 25 111
    row: 11:00 Finished Sichuan Blue Whales 12 21 27 20 80 | Live Update
    row: Zhejiang Lions 23 27 35 25 110
    row: 15:00 Finished Shenzhen Leopards 23 32 30 33 118 | Live Update
    row: Shandong Hi Speed 29 25 32 29 115
    row: 15:30 Finished Jilin Northeast Tigers 36 39 25 18 118 | Live Update
    row: Shanghai Sharks 15 25 32 36 108
    row: 19:35 Finished Beijing Ducks 24 20 17 22 83 | Live Update
    row: Beijing Royal Fighters 18 18 21 22 79
    row: 20:00 Finished Nanjing Monkey King 23 24 23 25 95 | Live Update
    row: Jiangsu Dragons 18 17 21 24 80
---
```

Full working code:

I added also `WebDriverWait` to wait for leagues.
And `row.text.replace('\n', ' | ')` to display row in one line

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1500, 1350)

# open url (sorry for the url , cause system always report its a spam)
driver.get("https://web2.sa8888.net/sport/Games.aspx?lang=3&device=pc")  # lang=3 for English

# jump to basketball
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menuList"]/div/ul/li[3]/div[2]/a[1]') 
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()
time.sleep(1)

# date menu
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="chooseDate"]')
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()

# jump to date 1
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dateOption"]/a[2]/span[1]')  # a[2] for second date, because first has no matches
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()

# close AD by double clicl
locator = (By.ID, 'btn_close') 
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(pointer).perform()

# wait for leagues
locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scheduleBottom"]/table[*]')
pointer = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(locator),
"element not found"
)

# list all leagues schedule
leagues = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scheduleBottom"]/table[*]')
print('len(leagues):', len(leagues))

for league in leagues:
    #print("Block.text=",Block.text,"\n")
    #_rows = Block.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    league_Title = league.find_element(By.TAG_NAME ,'caption')

    _rows = league.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@id, '_mainRow') or contains(@id, '_secondRow')]")
    print("\nleague:", league_Title.text, 'len(_rows)=', len(_rows))

    for row in _rows:
        #print(league_Title, row.text) #," / _rows=",_rows)
        # first_rows = Block.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, '_mainRow')]")
        # second_rows = Block.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, '_secondRow')]")
        print("\trow:", row.text.replace('\n', ' | '))  # <- clean text
        time.sleep(1)
    print('---')

time.sleep(120)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the url is block by system 

and here is the link : [ 
https : //web2.sa8888.net/sport/Games.aspx?lang=1&device=pc ]

Comment: in code you forgot `?` in `Games.aspx?lang=` and this made problem. I added results with `dot` and it seems it is solution for your problem.

Comment: now you can mark my answer as `accepted`. And if you would have bigger reputation (bigger score) then you could upvote my answer after few minutes.

Comment: BTW, is there any chance get earier data ? such like last 3 momth ?

Comment: it `DevTool` in `Chrome` I can see it uses `websocket` to send date and get values. Maybe if you could send older date then you could get older values - but Selenium rather doesn't have functions to use websockets and it may need to add some module or JavaScript code for this.

Comment: I'll give it a try, really appreciate.

Comment: Hi furas

I try to add an outer loop to get all date menu and wish to get the date format like yyyy/mm/dd  

Below is the code 

```
# list all date in menu
_dates = driver.find_eleme
for date in _dates:
    #date_text = date.find
    #_date_text = date.fin
    _date_text = date.find
    print(_date_text.text)

```
But I get the error message


```
 _date_text = date.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@rel="20*"]')
 {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@rel="20*"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)

```


Any recommendation ? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: better cteate new question on new page and put FULL errore message - it will more readable - because I don't see what error you get. And new people will see your problem so more people may help you. And if you have error then first you could use `print()` to check what you have in variables - I don't understand what you want with `data.fin` or `date.find`

Answer (score 0):

I think find_element() or find() is for Only one element on page. You will get just the first element of list of elements, if you use find_element() for multi elements on page.
And find_elements or findAll() is for all elements on page. This function will return data in Array format.
hope this help you some.